# Netlogo Create a list with all items by appending all items in turtle lists

Tags: list, netlogo

In my model, turtles have a list A with X number if items. I want to create a new list, which has the X number of items of every list A.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: so you simply want a list of the lengths of the lists? Can you give an example to make this a bit clearer?

Comment: When he says number of items, I think he means just all the items from.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a single list of all elements from all the turtles.

If you want a 2D list, then you could do the following,

```
let result [ A of turtles]
```

If you want a consolidated list (i.e. 1D list), then you could do the following,

```
let result reduce sentence [ A of turtles]
```